# Chaining promises in ES6/Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, fetch-api

I need to chain promises to make several GET requests and combine the data before using it elsewhere. I am having difficulty resolving the two promises. I've tried returning an array of the two promises before trying to use `.json()` but that doesn't work either.

```
activate() {

    // data is from http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos and
    // since there is not a photos2/ endpoint this is conceptual and 
    // represents batch importng
    return Promise.all([
        this.http.fetch('photos'),
        this.http.fetch('photos2')
    ]).then(responses => {

        console.log(responses); // see block of code below this for output

        // how can I combine the two promises here so I can resolve them with 'then' below?
        return responses[0].json(); // can return one response
        // return responses; //  doesn't work

    }).then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.photos = data;

    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

output of console.log(responses); :

```
[Response, Response]
0: Response
body: (...) // readablebytestream
bodyUsed : false
headers : Headers
ok : true
status : 200
statusText : "OK"
type : "cors"
url : "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos"
__proto__ : Object
1 : Response
 ....etc
```

Thank you!

Comment: `console.log(responses[0].json(), responses[1].json())`. Are there any promises? I doubt `json()` is asynchronous.

Comment: @Ryan It doesn't have to be.  It can be a value passed to the next promise.

Comment: Yes it logs two Promises that are resolved with the correct data. I must not be passing things correctly as my data variable. If I pass `responses` (commented out) then try to access them the same way (.json) in the next promise I get two promises that are pending with undefined values.

Comment: `return Promise.all(responses.map(r => r.json()));`, then?

Comment: In this case, the data is the same and being obtained using batch operations (first request is data 0-1000, second request data 1001-2000 etc) and I want to combine them. In other cases, I'm also curious about calls that aren't getting the same data like this example.

Comment: @bmb242 after getting result you can concat the data easyly

Comment: @bmb242 Deleted my answer... Ryan's suggestion is what you need.  Once you have the resulting objects, merge them however is appropriate for your use case and return the merged object for the next promise handler.

Comment: Perfect, I appreciate all of your help @Brad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the json data you want from the responses and send them to the next promise by mapping over them:

```
activate() {
    return Promise.all([
        this.http.fetch('photos'),
        this.http.fetch('photos2')
    ]).then(responses => {

        // this will send the actual json data 
        // you want to the next chained promise
        return responses.map(response => response.json())

    }).then(data => {

        // data is now an array of the the json objects 
        // you are trying to get from the requests
        console.log(data);
        this.photos = data;

    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

The first promise (in `Promise.all`) will send the requests. In the first `.then`, `responses` will be an array of the responses. Since you want the actual data from the responses, you can `map` over `responses` to get the data you want. Since this returns that, it will be passed into the next `.then`. At this point, `data` will be an array with the data you want from the responses.

It is then up to you to decide what you want to do with this data. If you want to "combine" them into a single object, then there are many ways to go about it (I would probably use the array reduce function for it, but that depends on the structure of the data and what you want from it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I decided to choose this answer as you explained things in detail

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be looking for

```
return Promise.all([responses[0].json(), responses[1].json()]);
```

Or just do

```
this.photos = Promise.all([
    this.http.fetch('photos').then(response => response.json()),
    this.http.fetch('photos2').then(response => response.json())
])
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much @Bergi it is greatly appreciated!!!